# Installing PHP in my home directory

Tags: php, c, linux, configure

I need to install PHP in my home directory, without  polluting any directory outside my home [very important requirement!]. In the system there is already an older version of PHP running.

I found instructions here:
http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/25/installing-php-and-apache-module-under-home/

I am running these commands in my home directory, as normal user `dan`

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/dan/php
$ make
$ INSTALL_ROOT=/home/dan/php make install
```

The author of the article states that you need to use both `--prefix` and `INSTALL_ROOT` to make sure nothing gets installed outside your home dir.

PHP gets installed (yeah!), however unfortunately it gets installed here:

```
/home/dan/php/php55/home/dan/php/php55/bin
```

whilst I was hoping to get it installed here:

```
/home/dan/php/php55/bin
```

What should I do? Should I use just one the directives? What's the neatest and conventional way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all simply:

```
INSTALL_ROOT=/ DESTDIR=/ make install
```

I think this because of this, but I am probably wrong:

You use both $PWD/configure --prefix= and the the INSTALL_ROOT
variable with make. Those two options are mutually exclusive.
When you use --prefix, you ask to add a path before each path of files to be installed in the make files. Then you use INSTALL_ROOT variable.

Configure create static make rules; so make couldn't have a way to make some difference:
It add the path you specified with configure a second time.

Answer (score 3):

In order to install php in your home directory (*Example: If you don't have root access but need a php executable*), run the following commands in your php download folder:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/my/path/
$ make install
```

As @Michael Tsang stated, you do not *need* to specify your install folder a second time as that will lead to the install creating the **duplicate** folder hierarchy in your install destination. I would also **recommend** compiling php with the `--with-openssl` if you're going to be working on a remote server, or using composer for example (*simply add the flag to the end of the first command*).

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
make install
```

since you have already configured it to be installed in your home. (Better to try it out on a non-root account first)